# Multi-writer (ArcGIS FME) for export to DGN

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, fme-form, dgn, data-interoperability

I would like to ask, if there is any way for export from one Reader (line geometry, format ArcSDE) to more writers (all in the same format DGN). Specific line with identical ID then would be displayed in Microstation for example twice, but with different symbology - lower line will be wider with different color and upper line will be thinner. I would like to induce effect of line´s border.

It would work together a connection of another writers, which would export to another formats (database) of output datasets except DGN?

Comment: Have you tried to just build a second writer and link the reader to it? I no longer have access to fme, but I know that I used to export to multiple writers from a single reader. If this isn't working for you, could you expand on the issues that you are having?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways you could do this.  As @MaryBeth mentioned, you can have multiple writers.

But, probably the easiest way would be to add a **[Cloner](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/FME_Transformers.htm#Transformers/cloner.htm)** transformer to copy the features coming in.  You can specify how many copies you want.  They'll all get an attribute which holds the copy number.

> The copy number attribute (by default, _copynum) will hold the copy
> number of each output feature. For example, if 3 copies of an input
> feature are made, the output copies will have 0, 1, and 2,
> respectively, assigned to their copy number attribute.

You can then filter by the _copynum attribute and direct the flow to set the symbology using the **[DGNStyler](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/FME_Transformers.htm#Transformers/dgnstyler.htm%3FTocPath%3DFME%2520Transformers%7CAll%2520Workbench%2520Transformers%7C_____109)** transformer.

Your workspace might look something like this:
[image]

After the DGNStylers, you can direct them both to the same writer.